# Altering the "From" or "Reply to" in google SMTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gmail

I want to provided "Email a friend" functionality to my site. I have a ASP.MVC site and I am using GMail as our provider (google apps for business).

So, a user will press my "Email a friend" button and be asked to enter their "reply to email address" and the persons email the wish to send the email to. I then use our log in credentials to send the email. The problem is the the "reply to" address is changed to the credentials address.

So bob@home.com wants to send an email to tom@home.com. He enters the correct email addresses for both tom and himself. But when tom get the email its reply to is "sendingsite@gmail.com" which are the log in credentials.

I have done some research on this and as far as i understand this is not possible in gmail.... I believe.

My question is two fold.

1. Is this possible in gmail?
2. If not, how would i go about getting this functionality?

I know there are third party tools which do this and are free etc but we dont want to use these due to privacy issues.

Comment: Post your code. How are you constructing the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`? What are you settings as the `From` address, and what are you settings as the `ReplyTo` address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Is this possible in gmail?* AFAIK it is not possible to change the FROM address to anything that is not either the google apps account name for the SMTP settings or an alias of it. I believe you can change the REPLYTO address. In `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`, there is a `ReplyToList` property. Are you setting the replyto there?
2. *If not, how would i go about getting this functionality?* Try something besides gmail / google apps for business. I have heard good things about [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/).

Also be careful with this. GA4B has a limit on the number of mails that can be sent in a specific time period. If you violate this, G will detect that you are abusing the service and lock the account you are sending mails from. They intend their service to be used by people, not machines, to send mail. All it takes is 1 automated attack on your send-to-friend page to disable your GA4B account, so consider a captcha or some other human-proof widget.

Comment: Thanks Danludwig. you were spot on. i did not post code as i thought because it was working (sending the mails) i did not need to, BUT you were on the money with the ReplyToList, somthing i am sure you would have seen earlier if i posted code :) sorry about that. I also did not know about "machines" using google and not people. we run all our machine generate mail through google. looks like we will have to look for some alternative. thanks again for you help.

Comment: We use GA4B to send some internal (machine) mail too, which is why I am familiar with the FROM/REPLYTO issue. I wouldn't say you **have to** find an alternative, just protect your accounts against abuse. A couple years ago a developer accidentally ran an infinite loop sending mails through GA4B and because of that we had to change the account we were sending mail from (it got disabled). If you have a user interface for sending mail, just add a captcha or something and you *should* be safe.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the advice. really appreciated it. I am looking into PoliteCaptcha at the moment to see if that suits us. I had been bashing my head against a wall all day yesterday trying to figure this issue and NO answer anywhere. Hope your answer will help some other poor soul(s) :)